# SwingWorker Extended but GUI still Frozen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, worker

This is my first time trying to use Swing components for a GUI, I am trying to implement a solution that allows a user to run 2 asynchronous remote commands.

The two commands in a nutshell are :

1. execute command on remote server
2. download data

My problem is that though I've employed a SwingWorker, my main menu still freezes. Moreover, the SwingWorker is passed through and the second command is execute prior to the first command being added.

I've gone through many, many examples and explanations online, and I feel like I'm still missing some crucial intuition that would allow me to make this work.

What is the problem with my swing worker, in that it will still freeze the GUI and isn't waiting until after completion to do the rest of the code?

Edit: Ultimately I want to also create a progress bar, which shows the amount of time left in the task before completion.

**GUI Class - Basic GUI with Buttons**

```
public TestGUI(){
      //code to show Gui with buttons

      //code also contains mouse listener:  
     btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { // listener
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            SampleClass.doRemoteTask();
        }

    });   

}
```

**Sample Class - Run Remote Command using Swing Worker in Background**

```
 public SampleClass(){

 public static void doRemoteTask(){
    //create sample worker
    final SampleWorker sampleworker = new SampleWorker(command, session); 

    //add change listener to wait for state change.
    sampleworker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if(StateValue.DONE == sampleworker.getState()){
                try {
                    Integer i = sampleworker.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    System.out.println("Could not get");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
        }
    });

  //do other stuff after the state DONE
  sampleworker.execute(); //sample worker is a long task. This is why it was created in the Swing Worker. 
   }

}
```

**Sample Worker Class - Run Command in Background**

```
protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
    byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
    int j = 0;
    publish("Start");
    while(true){
            //do stuff
            if(j % 100 == 0){
                setProgress(j);

        }
            //write to System.out then exit
            break;
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
    }
    publish("Completed");

    return j;
}
```

Comment: `SampleClass.doRemoteTask();` we have no idea what that method does. That method is invoked on the EDT which can cause the GUI to freeze if it invokes long running code.

Comment: SampleClass.doRemoteTask(); invokes a time consuming command on a remote server. I will edit my post to elaborate on the type of command and where I think the process is getting hung.

Comment: Exactly and that is what is causing the GUI to freeze. That method should start the SwingWorker, which in turn will invoke the command on the remote server.